# Different ways of modelling interactions between continuous and categorical predictors in GAM

Tags: r, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

The following question builds on the discussion found [on this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-include-an-interaction-term-in-gam).
Given a response variable `y`, a continuous explanatory variable `x` and a factor `fac`, it is possible to define a General Additive Model (GAM) with an interaction between `x` and `fac` using the argument `by=`. According to the [help file](http://127.0.0.1:12678/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html) `?gam.models` in the R package `mgcv`, this can be accomplished as follows:

```
gam1 <- gam(y ~ fac +s(x, by = fac), ...)
```

***@GavinSimpson*** [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-include-an-interaction-term-in-gam) suggests a different approach:

```
gam2 <- gam(y ~ fac +s(x) +s(x, by = fac, m=1), ...)
```

I have been playing around with a third model:

```
gam3 <- gam(y ~ s(x, by = fac), ...)
```

**My main questions are: are some of these models just wrong, or are they simply different? In the latter case, what are their differences?**
Based on the example that I am going to discuss below I think I could understand some of their differences, but I am still missing something.

As an example I am going to use a dataset with color spectra for flowers of two different plant species measured at different locations.

```
rm(list=ls())
# install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl) # allows accessing data from URL
df <- read.delim(text=getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcoplebani85/datasets/master/flower_color_spectra.txt"))
library(mgcv)
```

These are the mean color spectra at the locality level for the two species (rolling means were used):

[image]

Each color refers to a different species. Each line refers to a different locality.

My final goal is to model the (potentially interactive) effect of `Taxon` and wavelength `wl` on % reflectance (referred to as `density` in the code and dataset) while accounting for `Locality` as a random effect in a mixed-effect GAM. For the moment I won't add the mixed effect part to my plate, which is already full enough with trying to understand how to model interactions.

I'll start with the simplest of the three interactive GAMs:

```
gam.interaction0 <- gam(density ~ s(wl, by = Taxon), data = df) 
# common intercept, different slopes
plot(gam.interaction0, pages=1)
```

[image]

```
summary(gam.interaction0)
```

Produces:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
density ~ s(wl, by = Taxon)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  28.3490     0.1693   167.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                      edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesA 8.938  8.999 884.3  <2e-16 ***
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB 8.838  8.992 325.5  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.523   Deviance explained = 52.4%
GCV = 284.96  Scale est. = 284.42    n = 9918
```

The parametric part is the same for both species, but different splines are fitted for each species. It is a bit confusing to have a parametric part in the summary of GAMs, which are non-parametric. ***@IsabellaGhement*** explains:

> If you look at the plots of the estimated smooth effects (smooths)
> corresponding to your first model, you will notice that they are
> centered about zero. So you need to 'shift' those smooths up (if the
> estimated intercept is positive) or down (if the estimated intercept
> is negative) to obtain the smooth functions you thought you were
> estimating. In other words, you need to add the estimated intercept to
> the smooths to get at what you really want. For your first model, the
> 'shift' is assumed to be the same for both smooths.

Moving on:

```
gam.interaction1 <- gam(density ~ Taxon +s(wl, by = Taxon, m=1), data = df)
plot(gam.interaction1,pages=1)
```

[image]

```
summary(gam.interaction1)
```

Gives:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
density ~ Taxon + s(wl, by = Taxon, m = 1)

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    40.3132     0.1482   272.0   <2e-16 ***
TaxonSpeciesB -26.0221     0.2186  -119.1   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                      edf Ref.df    F p-value    
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesA 7.978      8 2390  <2e-16 ***
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB 7.965      8  879  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.803   Deviance explained = 80.3%
GCV = 117.89  Scale est. = 117.68    n = 9918
```

Now, each species also have its own parametric estimate.

The next model is the one that I have trouble understanding:

```
gam.interaction2 <- gam(density ~ Taxon + s(wl) + s(wl, by = Taxon,  m=1), data = df)
plot(gam.interaction2, pages=1)
```

[image]

I have no clear idea of what these graphs represent.

```
summary(gam.interaction2)
```

Gives:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
density ~ Taxon + s(wl) + s(wl, by = Taxon, m = 1)

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    40.3132     0.1463   275.6   <2e-16 ***
TaxonSpeciesB -26.0221     0.2157  -120.6   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                      edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(wl)               8.940  8.994 30.06  <2e-16 ***
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesA 8.001  8.000 11.61  <2e-16 ***
s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB 8.001  8.000 19.59  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.808   Deviance explained = 80.8%
GCV = 114.96  Scale est. = 114.65    n = 9918
```

The parametric part of `gam.interaction2` is about the same as for `gam.interaction1`, but now there are three estimates for smooth terms, which I cannot interpret.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will take the time to help me understand the differences in the three models.

Comment: What a beautiful post, Marco!  If you look at the plots of the estimated smooth effects (smooths) corresponding to your first model, you will notice that they are centered about zero.  So you need to 'shift' those smooths up (if the estimated intercept is positive) or down (if the estimated intercept is negative) to obtain the smooth functions you thought you were estimating.  In other words, you need to add the estimated intercept to the smooths to get at what you really want. For your first model, the 'shift' is assumed to be the same for both smooths.

Comment: When specifying your model, it seems to me that you shoud have a main effect for Taxon, a main (smooth) effect for wl and a (smooth) interaction between Taxon and wl. The link to Gavin Simpson's post suggests this is how he sets up models of this kind. He also seems to use the same value of k for the smooth effects in the model. Usually, if you include an interaction term between two predictor variables, you should also include the main effects for those variables.

Comment: So I would discard your first model, since it omits the main effect of Taxon. Just use Gavin's suggestion to get the main effects and interaction effects you need (while remembering that smooths produced by the model are centered about 0 by default and need to be 'shifted' up or down depending on the intercept term(s).

Comment: Hi @IsabellaGhement and thanks for your feedback. How would you interpret the fact that summary(gam.interaction2) produces a significance estimate for s(wl) relative to each species but also one for s(wl) not linked to either species? Is that the effect of wl on the smoothing function of y (density in my case) regardless of Taxon? Is it computed simply by fitting density ~ s(wl)? I run such model and it does estimate a parametric coeff. very close to the mean of the parametric coeff. of the two species, and the associated edf are very close to those of s(wl) given by summary(gam.interaction2).

Comment: IMHO, the right way is the third and it entails with the concept of marginality. The model is built from simple to complex so it includes the main effects (factor & smooth), and then the interaction. This way allows you to inspect their significance. The effect of every variable + interaction is decomposed. It is the easier to understand. The first curve shows you the common effect of the variable wl and the seccond and the third the interactions of wl and the taxon. As you can see they are pretty much simple compared to former options.

Comment: If by "third way" you mean `gam3` then that is wrong (the `by` smooths are centred so you need the parametric terms). If you meant the third way the OP shows in the extended answer, then I agree with you to some extent, although we have to now deal with identifiability issues; the multiple smooths of `wl` do cause problems in many case that mean we need to add some extra shrinkage. The `gam1` approach is also fine. In this instance, I would suggest using the `gam1` approach, increasing `k` if needed, and handling the `SampleID` issue as I describe in my answer below.

Comment: Colleagues and I have a paper in press [(preprint here)](https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.27320v1) that goes into a *lot* of detail on these issues. You might find that helpful for both grokking the range of models that can be fitted and how to choose among them. For me, I think that all you need here is `gam1` **plus** something for the `SampleID` effect plus you need to do something about the non-constant variance problem; These data don't seem to be conditionally distributed Gaussian because of the lower bound.

Comment: @MarcoPlebani I circled back to this after sometime. I noticed that the response `density` is negative at small wavelengths for some observations. I also noted that you mention the data are % reflectance. Are those negative `density` values real? If so, how do they arise? Is it via some normalization? If these are real, that excludes the Tweedie family and the Gamma. If this is a true %, (question remains why are there some negative values) and assuming the negative values can be excluded (or something?), then a beta regression `family = betar()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @GavinSimpson hello! Those negative values are spurious, due to instrument error. I thought I had removed them from the example dataset. You are right on `family = betar()` probably being a better candidate than Tweedie/Gamma. Well spotted, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`gam1` and `gam2` are fine; they are different models, although they are trying to do the same thing, which is model group-specific smooths.

The `gam1` form

```
y ~ f + s(x, by = f)
```

does this by estimating a separate smoother for each level of `f` (assuming that `f` is a standard factor), and indeed, a separate smoothness parameter is estimated for each smooth also.

The `gam2` form

```
y ~ f + s(x) + s(x, by = f, m = 1)
```

achieves the same aim as `gam1` (of modelling the smooth relationship between `x` and `y` for each level of `f`) but it does so by estimating a global or average smooth effect of `x` on `y` (the `s(x)` term) *plus* a smooth difference term (the second `s(x, by = f, m = 1)` term). As the penalty here is on the first derivative (`m = 1`) for this difference smoother, it is penalising departure from a flat line, which when added to the global or average smooth term (`s(x)`) reflects a deviation from the global or average effect.

`gam3` form

```
y ~ s(x, by = f)
```

is wrong regardless of how well it may fit in a particular situation. The reason I say it is wrong is that each smooth specified by the `s(x, by = f)` part is centred about zero because of the sum-to-zero constraint imposed for model identifiability. As such, there is nothing in the model that accounts for the mean of $Y$ in each of the groups defined by `f`. There is only the overall mean given by the model intercept. This means that smoother, which is centred about zero and which has had the flat basis function removed from the basis expansion of `x` (as it is confounded with the model intercept) is now responsible for modelling both the difference in the mean of $Y$ for the current group and the overall mean (model intercept), plus the smooth effect of `x` on $Y$.

None of these models is appropriate for your data however; ignoring, for now, the wrong distribution for the response (`density` can't be negative and there is a heterogeneity issue which a non-Gaussian `family` would fix or address), you haven't taken into account the grouping by flower (`SampleID` in your dataset).

If your aim is to model `Taxon` specific curves then a model of the form would be a starting point:

```
m1 <- gam(density ~ Taxon + s(wl, by = Taxon, k = 20) + s(SampleID, bs = 're'),
          data = df, method = 'REML')
```

where I have added a random effect for `SampleID` and boosted the size of the basis expansion for the `Taxon` specific smooths.

This model, `m1`, models the observations as coming from either a smooth `wl` effect depending on which species (`Taxon`) the observation comes from (the `Taxon` parametric term just sets the mean `density` for each species and is needed as discussed above), plus a random intercept. Taken together, the curves for individual flowers arise from shifted versions of the `Taxon` specific curves, with the amount of shift given by the random intercept. This model assumes that all individuals have the same shape of smooth as given by the smooth for the particular `Taxon` that individual flower comes from.

Another version of this model is the `gam2` form from above but with an added random effect

```
m2 <- gam(density ~ Taxon + s(wl) + s(wl, by = Taxon, m = 1) + s(SampleID, bs = 're'),
          data = df, method = 'REML')
```

This model fits better but I don't think it is solving the problem at all, see below. One thing I think it does suggest is that the default `k` is potentially too low for the `Taxon` specific curves *in these models*. There is still a lot of residual smooth variation that we're not modelling if you look at the diagnostic plots.

This model is more than likely too restrictive for your data; some of the curves in your plot of the individual smooths do not appear to be simply shifted versions of the `Taxon` average curves. A more complex model would allow for individual-specific smooths too. Such a model can be estimated using the `fs` or *factor-smooth interaction basis*. We still want `Taxon` specific curves but we also want to have a separate smooth for each `SampleID`, but unlike the `by` smooths, I would suggest that initially, you want all of those `SampleID`-specific curves to have the same wiggliness. In the same sense as the random intercept that we included earlier, the `fs` basis adds a random intercept, but also includes a "random" spline (I use the scare quotes as in a Bayesian interpretation of the GAM, all these models are just variations on random effects).

This model is fitted for your data as

```
m3 <- gam(density ~ Taxon + s(wl, by = Taxon, k = 20) + s(wl, SampleID, bs = 'fs'), 
          data = df, method = 'REML')
```

Note that I have increased `k` here, in case we need more wiggliness in the `Taxon`-specific smooths. We still need the `Taxon` parametric effect for the reasons explained above.

That model takes a *long* time to fit on a single core with `gam()` — `bam()` will most likely be better at fitting this model as there are a relatively large number of random effects here.

If we compare these models with a smoothness parameter selection-corrected version of AIC we see just how dramatically better this latter model, `m3`, is compared to the other two even though it uses an order of magnitude more degrees of freedom

```
> AIC(m1, m2, m3)
          df      AIC
m1  190.7045 67264.24
m2  192.2335 67099.28
m3 1672.7410 31474.80
```

If we look at this model's smooths we get a better idea of how it is fitting the data:

[image]

(Note this was produced using `draw(m3)` using the `draw()` function from my *gratia* package. The colours in the lower-left plot are irrelevant and don't help here.)

Each `SampleID`'s fitted curve is built up from either the intercept or the parametric term `TaxonSpeciesB` plus one of the two `Taxon`-specific smooths, depending on to which `Taxon` each `SampleID` belongs, *plus* its own `SampleID`-specifc smooth.

Note that all these models are still wrong as they don't account for the heterogeneity; gamma or Tweedie models with a log link would be my choices to take this further. Something like:

```
m4 <- gam(density ~ Taxon + s(wl, by = Taxon) + s(wl, SampleID, bs = 'fs'), 
          data = df, method = 'REML', family = tw())
```

But I'm having trouble with this model fitting at the moment, which might indicate it is too complex with multiple smooths of `wl` included.

An alternative form is to use the ordered factor approach, which does an ANOVA-like decomposition on the smooths:

- `Taxon` parametric term is retained
- `s(wl)` is a smooth that will represent the *reference* level
- `s(wl, by = Taxon)` will have a separate *difference* smooth for each other level. In your case, you'll have only one of these.

This model is fitted like `m3`,

```
df <- transform(df, fTaxon = ordered(Taxon))
m3 <- gam(density ~ fTaxon + s(wl) + s(wl, by = fTaxon) +
            s(wl, SampleID, bs = 'fs'), 
          data = df, method = 'REML')
```

but the interpretation is different; the first `s(wl)` will refer to `TaxonA` and the smooth implied by `s(wl, by = fTaxon)` will be a smooth difference between the smooth for `TaxonA` and that of `TaxonB`.

Comment: Thanks! My next question would have been "but why summaries differ whether a factor is ordered or not?" but you beat me to it, thanks for that as well. In my dataset each `SampleID` is a spectrogram from a single flower, each from a different plant, so I don't think `SampleID` should be specified as random (but correct me if I'm wrong). I have indeed used a model similar to your `m3` with `Taxon` as ordered factor, but specifying `+ s(Locality, bs="re") + s(Locality, wl, bs="re")` as random. I'll look into the issues you raise about the distribution of residuals and heteroskedasticity. Cheers!

Comment: I would still include `SampleID` as random the data from a single flower are likely to be related and moreso it if the entire function that relates to the flower, so in a sense the functions (smooths) are random. You might also need a plain random effect for plant if there were multiple flowers per plant and multiple plants per taxon in the study (use the `bs = 're'` "smooth" I mentioned earlier in the answer.

Comment: When I tried to fit `m3` with `family = Gamma(link = 'log')` or `family = tw()` I was getting real problems with *mgcv* not being able to find good starting values and other errors causing *mgcv* to crap out, which I haven't gotten to the bottom of yet. Certainly from the data you provided a Gaussian model is not right. I did get a Gaussian with log link to fit and it helped but it is not capturing all the heterogeneity either.

Answer (score 6):

This is what Jacolien van Rij [writes](https://jacolienvanrij.com/Tutorials/GAMM.html) in her tutorial page:

> How to set up the interaction depends on the type of grouping
> predictor:

> - with factor include intercept difference: `Group + s(Time, by=Group)`
> - with ordered factor include intercept difference and
>   reference smooth: `Group + s(Time) + s(Time, by=Group)`
> - with binary predictor include reference smooth: `s(Time) + s(Time, by=IsGroupChildren)`

Categorical variables must be specified as factors, ordered factors, or binary factors with the appropriate R functions.
To understand how to interpret the outputs and what each model can and cannot tell us, see [Jacolien van Rij's tutorial page](https://jacolienvanrij.com/Tutorials/GAMM.html) directly. Her tutorial also explains how to fit mixed-effect GAMs.
To understand the concept of interactions in the context of GAMs, [this](https://petolau.github.io/Analyzing-double-seasonal-time-series-with-GAM-in-R/) tutorial page by Peter Laurinec is also useful. Both pages provide plenty further information to run GAMs correctly in different scenarios.