# How 'by' factor works with 'fs' random smooth in gam?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, smoothing

I've a large dataset including a response `bmk`, a continuous predictor `delay`, a `group` factor (n=2, 0 and 1), and a random effect `medu` (n=85).

I split the whole dataset (`dat`) into two subdatasets (`dat0` and `dat1`) based on the group factor.

Then, I run the `m0` and `m1` gam using `bs='fs'` separately, applied on `dat0` and `dat1`, respectively.
And then, I run the `m2` gam on the whole dataset, applying `bs='fs'` for each `by=group` factor.

The smooth of group=1 (red) is exactly the same between `m1` and `m2`, but why is the smooth of group=0 (blue) different between `m0` and `m2`?

**Models:**

```
m0 <- bam(bmk ~ s(delay, medu, bs="fs", m=2),
          data = dat0, method = 'fREML', 
          family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), 
          discrete = TRUE)

m1 <- bam(bmk ~ s(delay, medu, bs="fs", m=2),
          data = dat1, method = 'fREML', 
          family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), 
          discrete = TRUE)

m2 <- bam(bmk ~ group + s(delay, medu, bs="fs", by=group, m=2),
          data = dat, method = 'fREML', 
          family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), 
          discrete = TRUE)
```

**Plots:**

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3), cex = 1.1)
plot_smooth(m0, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), main = "m0", 
            col=c("blue"))
plot_smooth(m1, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), main = "m1", 
            col=c("red"))
plot_smooth(m2, view="delay", plot_all="group", rm.ranef=FALSE, 
            n.grid = 50, col=c("blue","red"),
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), main = "m2")
```

[image]

---

Thanks Gavin for these relevant explanations/hypotheses.

**Some precision about the data:**
`bmk`: the outcome, a biomarker known to vary with `delay`.
`group`: factor, two different conditions of blood sampling (0 and 1), for which I'd like to compare the bmk~delay smoothed relationships and quantify the difference over `delay`.
`medu`: factor, n=85 medical units from which `bmk` may have different levels of results, which could vary in a non-linear way over `delay` (that's why I chose `bs='fs'` random smooth for `medu`).
Note that the number (n=85) and type of `medu` is strictly identical for `group`=0 (`dat0`), `group`=1 (`dat1`), and `group`=0+1 (`dat`); however, the number of `bmk` results by `medu` is different between `group`=0 and `group`=1, their sums being the number of `bmk` from `group`=0+1 (see below the counts provided in `n_medu` data).

**n_medu data:**

```
n_medu <-
structure(list(medu = structure(1:85, .Label = c("21110", "21134", 
"21149", "21175", "21187", "21194", "21195", "21266", "21294", 
"21357", "21551", "21555", "21773", "24022", "24024", "24102", 
"24105", "24106", "24107", "24108", "24109", "24112", "24114", 
"24116", "24121", "24122", "24132", "24142", "24147", "24148", 
"24153", "24161", "24162", "24530", "24803", "24812", "24816", 
"24820", "24827", "24886", "24887", "31023", "31302", "31304", 
"31321", "31736", "31800", "33026", "33027", "33028", "33031", 
"33071", "33090", "33091", "33107", "33116", "33128", "33149", 
"33180", "33223", "33251", "33261", "33341", "33510", "33516", 
"33821", "33911", "34024", "34104", "34131", "34188", "36027", 
"36028", "36029", "36103", "36108", "36109", "36110", "36119", 
"36140", "36173", "36313", "36326", "36500", "36724"), class = "factor"), 
    nb_dat0 = c(8L, 5946L, 1970L, 40L, 1033L, 2422L, 45L, 557L, 
    60L, 50L, 396L, 45L, 71L, 684L, 39L, 15L, 1328L, 485L, 46L, 
    18L, 22L, 6350L, 29L, 20L, 4009L, 677L, 762L, 3737L, 37L, 
    321L, 1185L, 1295L, 1779L, 180L, 1572L, 18L, 24L, 15L, 89L, 
    64L, 25L, 120L, 308L, 525L, 103L, 55L, 5434L, 85L, 31L, 171L, 
    26L, 11L, 126L, 9L, 5768L, 891L, 1121L, 1220L, 239L, 30L, 
    1846L, 10L, 54L, 29L, 107L, 140L, 59L, 33L, 819L, 20L, 432L, 
    836L, 237L, 54L, 8786L, 623L, 513L, 8604L, 20L, 9670L, 40L, 
    300L, 110L, 60L, 10L), nb_dat1 = c(22L, 8009L, 3253L, 50L, 
    3726L, 2521L, 215L, 539L, 154L, 16L, 109L, 12L, 119L, 240L, 
    46L, 21L, 1138L, 653L, 56L, 26L, 27L, 7738L, 22L, 16L, 8806L, 
    140L, 280L, 4296L, 14L, 96L, 1471L, 3078L, 162L, 40L, 1943L, 
    29L, 59L, 18L, 17L, 27L, 8L, 60L, 133L, 123L, 76L, 40L, 3616L, 
    84L, 48L, 215L, 22L, 23L, 283L, 33L, 6369L, 818L, 1987L, 
    809L, 564L, 19L, 1167L, 30L, 52L, 7L, 97L, 166L, 31L, 21L, 
    691L, 14L, 80L, 885L, 315L, 29L, 6339L, 345L, 489L, 6922L, 
    10L, 10033L, 21L, 61L, 52L, 85L, 30L), nb_dat = c(30L, 13955L, 
    5223L, 90L, 4759L, 4943L, 260L, 1096L, 214L, 66L, 505L, 57L, 
    190L, 924L, 85L, 36L, 2466L, 1138L, 102L, 44L, 49L, 14088L, 
    51L, 36L, 12815L, 817L, 1042L, 8033L, 51L, 417L, 2656L, 4373L, 
    1941L, 220L, 3515L, 47L, 83L, 33L, 106L, 91L, 33L, 180L, 
    441L, 648L, 179L, 95L, 9050L, 169L, 79L, 386L, 48L, 34L, 
    409L, 42L, 12137L, 1709L, 3108L, 2029L, 803L, 49L, 3013L, 
    40L, 106L, 36L, 204L, 306L, 90L, 54L, 1510L, 34L, 512L, 1721L, 
    552L, 83L, 15125L, 968L, 1002L, 15526L, 30L, 19703L, 61L, 
    361L, 162L, 145L, 40L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -85L))
```

Summaries of the 3 `plot_smooth` show the same `medu` reference level ('36140'), which is the one with the higher number of `bmk` results (n=19703, as shown on the sorted `n_medu$n_dat` column).
Therefore, *a priori* the number, type and/or reference level of `medu` are not the cause of the problem.

```
Summary: # plot_smooth on dat0
  * delay : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 90.000000. 
  * medu : factor; set to the value(s): 36140.
Summary: # plot_smooth on dat1
  * delay : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 90.000000. 
  * medu : factor; set to the value(s): 36140.
Summary: # plot_smooth on dat
  * group : factor; set to the value(s): 0, 1. 
  * delay : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 90.000000. 
  * medu : factor; set to the value(s): 36140.
```

Rather suspecting a distribution-related issue, I finally solved the problem with evenly spaced knots (intuitively but somewhat unexpectedly, in any case without being able to demonstrate it).

My conclusion is that knots should be evenly spaced when a `bs='fs'` random smooth effect is wanted for each `by=` factor specifically, within a common smooth term.

I assume this nested model to be similar to the `model I` from [Pedersen et al](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) (i.e., no global shared trend but group-level trends and different smoothness (individual penalties)), or at least closer to `model I` than `model GI`, isn't it?

**Models with evenly spaced knots:**

```
# group=0
dat0_knots <- list(delay = seq(min(dat0$delay), max(dat0$delay), 
                   length = 10))
m3 <- bam(bmk ~
            s(delay, medu, bs="fs", k=10, m=2),
          data = dat0, method = 'fREML', family = 
          inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), control = ctrl, 
          discrete = TRUE, knots = dat0_knots)
m3_fit <- plot_smooth(m3, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, 
                      n.grid = 50, xlim=c(0,90), 
                      ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
                      main = "m3\n(k=10 evenly spaced)", 
                      col=c("blue"));summary()

# group=1
dat1_knots <- list(delay = seq(min(dat1$delay), max(dat1$delay), 
                  length = 10))
m4 <- bam(bmk ~
            s(delay, medu, bs="fs", k=10, m=2),
          data = dat1, method = 'fREML', 
          family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), 
          control = ctrl, discrete = TRUE, knots = dat1_knots)
m4_fit <- plot_smooth(m4, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, 
                     n.grid = 50, xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
                     main = "m3\n(k=10 evenly spaced)", 
                     col=c("red"));summary()

# group=0 & group=1
dat_knots <- list(delay = seq(min(dat$delay), max(dat$delay), 
                  length = 10))
m5 <- bam(bmk ~
            group +
            s(delay, medu, bs="fs", k=10, by=group, m=2),
          data = dat, method = 'fREML', 
          family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), 
          control = ctrl, discrete = TRUE, knots = dat_knots)
m5_fit <- plot_smooth(m5, view="delay", plot_all="group", 
                      rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
                      col=c("blue","red"),
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
            main = "m5\n(k=10 evenly spaced)");summary()

# plots
par(mfrow = c(1,3), cex = 1.1, xpd=NA)
plot_smooth(m3, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
            main = "m3\n(k=10 evenly spaced)", col=c("blue"))
plot_smooth(m4, view="delay", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
            main = "m4\n(k=10 evenly spaced)", col=c("red"))
plot_smooth(m5, view="delay", plot_all="group", rm.ranef=FALSE, 
            n.grid = 50, col=c("blue","red"),
            xlim=c(0,90), ylim=c(11.5,14.5), 
            main = "m5\n(k=10 evenly spaced)")
abline(h=min(m3_fit[["fv"]][["fit"]]), 
       col=adjustcolor("blue", alpha=0.5), lty = "dashed")
abline(h=max(m3_fit[["fv"]][["fit"]]), 
       col=adjustcolor("blue", alpha=0.5), lty = "dashed")
abline(h=min(m4_fit[["fv"]][["fit"]]), 
       col=adjustcolor("red", alpha=0.5), lty = "dashed")
abline(h=max(m4_fit[["fv"]][["fit"]]), 
       col=adjustcolor("red", alpha=0.5), lty = "dashed")
```

**Plots of smooths:**

[image]

Below are the `plot_diff` (with and without `sim.ci`) I was looking for:

```
  par(mfrow = c(1,2), cex = 1.1)
  plot_diff <- plot_diff(m5, view = "delay", 
                 comp=list(group=c('1', '0')), ylim=c(-0.5,2), 
                 rm.ranef=FALSE, sim.ci = FALSE, 
                 main = "m5\n(k=10 evenly spaced)\nsim.ci=FALSE")
  plot_diff_sim.ci <- plot_diff(m5, view = "delay", 
                 comp=list(group=c('1', '0')), ylim=c(-0.5,2), 
                 rm.ranef=FALSE, sim.ci = TRUE, 
                 main = "m5\n(k=10 evenly spaced)\nsim.ci=TRUE")
```

**Plots of smooths difference:**

[image]

---

Indeed, my `m2` and `m5` models have both two separate sets of smooths, one per group, each with their own smoothing parameters.
However, it does not explain the initial issue that is the discordance between the separate smooth of group=0 `m0` and the smooth of the same group=0 in the `by=group` `m2` from the whole data.
Furthermore, it does not explain why this discrepancy disappears when the location of knots is fixed in the 3 cases (`m3`, `m4`, `m5`).
The two `by=group` models `m2` and `m5` are not similar (see below). I would be tempted to prefer `m5` (knots spaced evenly) since it corresponds exactly to the superposition of individual `m3` and `m4`.
However, its AIC is higher, and the `compareML` function gives `m2` preferentially (the lowest AIC).
So, which `by=group` model is the most reliable?

**Models m2 and m5**

```
# m2
m2 <- bam(bmk ~
            group +
            s(delay, medu, bs="fs", k=10, by=group, m=2),
          data = dat, method = 'fREML', family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), control = ctrl, discrete = TRUE)
AIC(m2) # AIC = 979297.2 (deviance explained = 9.8%)

# m5: knots spaced evenly
dat_knots <- list(delay = seq(min(dat$delay), max(dat$delay), length = 10))
m5 <- bam(bmk ~
            group +
            s(delay, medu, bs="fs", k=10, by=group, m=2),
          data = dat, method = 'fREML', family = inverse.gaussian(link="identity"), control = ctrl, discrete = TRUE, knots = dat_knots)
AIC(m5) # AIC = 979406.6 (deviance explained = 9.83%)

> compareML(m2,m5)
m2: bmk ~ group + s(delay, medu, bs = "fs", k = 10, by = group, m = 2)
m5: bmk ~ group + s(delay, medu, bs = "fs", k = 10, by = group, m = 2) # knots spaced evenly
Model m2 preferred: lower fREML score (60.692), and equal df (0.000).
-----
  Model     Score Edf Difference    Df
1    m5 -182452.8   8                 
2    m2 -182513.5   8     60.692 0.000
AIC difference: -109.39, model m2 has lower AIC.
```

**Plots**

[image]

**Test of Gavin's proposals**

Using `knots=list(delay=sort(unique(dat0$delay)))` in each separate group slightly improved the issue by making `group=0` smooth slightly more nonlinear (`m6`) as compared to `m0`. Note that `delay` ranges from 4 to 90 min, i.e., 86 unique integer values. However, the initial discrepancy issue tends to disappear even further (i.e., the nonlinearity of group=0 tends to increase) using `knots=list(delay=seq(4,90,2))`, but it tends to reappear using other sequences of locations (e.g., `knots=list(delay=seq(4,90,4))` or `knots=list(delay=seq(4,90,10))`). This is certainly due to the non continuous distribution of delay, especially the isolated subgroup at delay below 8 and above 15 min (see `gratia::appraise(m6)` below).

[image]

```
gratia::appraise(m6)
```

[image]

The solution seems to be, indeed, to add `xt=list(bs="cr")` within the smooth term of the three models (`m9`, `m10`, `m11`) without specifying the number of `k=` nor `knots=`, which gives the best deviance explained (`summary(m11)`: 9.84%):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you produced those plots. I assume `medu` is coded as a factor? Your last model is missing `group` as a parametric factor effect - this likely explains the difference but I still don't understand how you could possibly achieve those plots if `medu` really was coded as a factor

Comment: @Gavin, I've verified: `group` and `medu` are both factors (to be sure, I just reapplied `as.factor()` for both in the 3 dataset). Adding `group` as parametric factor effect (edit) doesn't change anything. I used `itsadug::plot_smooth()` for plots (edit); did I forget an argument? Is it possible to reproduce these 3 plots with gratia in order to compare?

Comment: Why are you using "fs" when you only have 2 groups? To quote https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html > bs="fs" A special smoother class (see smooth.construct.fs.smooth.spec) is available for the case in which a smooth is required at each of a large number of factor levels (for example a smooth for each patient in a study), and each smooth should have the same smoothing parameter. The "fs" smoothers are set up to be efficient when used with gamm, and have penalties on each null sapce component (i.e. they are fully ‘random effects’)

Comment: @Lukas, I use `bs='fs'` to apply the random smooth effect of `medu` (n=85 medical units) on each `group` (two different blood sampling conditions), knowing that my final objective is to test if the smoothed relationships of `bmk` (a biomarker) with `delay` differs between the two groups (using `itsadug::plot_diff`).
Such a model combining `bs='fs'` and `by=factor` seems possible (see `m3` and `m4` models on this post [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403772/different-ways-of-modelling-interactions-between-continuous-and-categorical-pred?rq=1)), but would there be some limit?

Comment: Given what you wrote in your first (now deleted) answer, I think it is the difference in the knot locations (unique data) and hence the set of low-rank TPRS basis functions created from the full basis that is causing the discrepancy you report. However, with the TPRS (default smooth) it's tricky to fix that. If you add `xt = list(bs = "cr")` and pass in the required knots you might make progress and find the estimated functions are similar. What you show in this answer is as a result of not providing sufficient knots for the TPRS basis hence the poor `m5` performance.

Comment: I think what you can try for the TPRS basis is to compute `knots` based on the full data set as `knots = list(delay = sort(unique(dat$delay))`, and then use that in the models for each separate group or in `m5` (I would expect `m2` and `m5` to then be indistinguishable as using the unique data values [assuming there are fewer than 2000 - more than that behaviour changes again] is what mgcv will be doing by default with the TPRS basis). See `?tprs` for more details on `knots` with these smooths.

Comment: Many thanks Gavin. My answer in the edited "Test of Gavin's proposals".

Answer (score 3):

You missed some important output from `plot_smooth()` and some critical understanding about what the function is doing. The reason I was confused absent knowledge about what `plot_smooth()` was doing is that the models you specified have up to 85 smooths (depending on how the levels of `medu` fall into the `group`s) and yet the plots showed a single smooth per `group`. This doesn't make sense — why just one smooth? What does that smooth represent for each group? — unless you understand what `plot_smooth()` is doing.

Looking at the printed output that `plot_smooth()` sends to the console explains what must be going on.

Here is a reproducible example using the `simdat` data set from *itsadug*:

```r
library("mgcv")
library("itsadug")
library("dplyr")
data(simdat) 

# Model with random effect and interactions: 
m3 <- bam(Y ~ Group + s(Time, Subject, by = Group, bs='fs', m=2, k=5), 
          data = simdat)

df1 <- simdat |>
  filter(Group == "Adults")

m1 <- bam(Y ~ s(Time, Subject, bs='fs', m=2, k=5), 
          data = df1)

df2 <- simdat |>
  filter(Group == "Children")

m2 <- bam(Y ~ s(Time, Subject, bs='fs', m=2, k=5), 
          data = df2)

op <- par(mfrow = c(1,3), cex = 1.1)
plot_smooth(m1, view="Time", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, main = "Adults", 
            col=c("blue"))
plot_smooth(m2, view="Time", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, main = "Children", 
            col=c("red"))
plot_smooth(m3, view="Time", plot_all="Group", rm.ranef=FALSE, n.grid = 50, 
            col=c("blue","red"), main = "Both")
par(op)
```

This produces:

[image]

where the effects show are clearly different, more so than in your actual example.

What's going on?

Look at the output from `plot_smooth()` that is printed to the console:

```
Summary:
    * Time : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 2000.000000. 
    * Subject : factor; set to the value(s): a01. # <--- here!
Summary:
    * Time : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 2000.000000. 
    * Subject : factor; set to the value(s): c01. # <--- here!
Summary:
    * Group : factor; set to the value(s): Adults, Children. 
    * Time : numeric predictor; with 50 values ranging from 0.000000 to 2000.000000. 
    * Subject : factor; set to the value(s): a01. # <--- here!
```

Note what is states about the subjects chosen for the three plots. In `m1` the subject `a01` was chosen, while in `m2` the subject `c01` was chosen. For `m3` we are back to `a01`. This explains why one of the curves matches across the three plots but the other doesn't. The reason what different subjects is because of your subsetting the data - subject `a01` in this example is only in one of the Child or Adult groups, for obvious reasons. Hence, when you are  plotting these smooths for the individual models there is no way that it could show the same subject across all three models/plots.

In your case it is reasonable to assume that the *same* medical unit is present in both groups, but it is also reasonable to assume that the default/reference level of the `medu` factor *in the data used to fit the subset models* is different. `gam()` and `bam()` drop empty levels on factors, which, combined with the previous point will mean than different `medu` levels from the full data set become the reference level in the subsets of data, and hence you see the behaviour that you ask about; the `medu` level in the two data subset plots is different and hence one of the smooths in the combined model/plot will not match with one of the two plots for the data subset models.

The solution could be to specify the `medu` level you want to show in all plots, assuming that one level is present in all groups?

But I would ask you why you want this plot? Why do you want to focus on a specific subject? What are you trying to show for these smooths? If it is to show some kind of average effect in the two groups, conditioning on a single subject would be a bit weird. If you explain a bit more about why you are doing what you are doing, I can suggest an alternative way to proceed.